# Issue installing Microsoft Viual Studio Community edition v2017

Tags: visual-studio, failed-installation

I've been trying to install VSCommunity Edition for the last few hours with no luck. If you check the screenshot attached. You'll see that I can change the directories for installation for the first 2 requirements, but im unable to change the directory for the 3rd option (the SDK install along with others) which just happen to be the very large percentage of files. It's wanting to install over 45gb of files on my C Drive which is just a 50gb SSD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mjit.jpg)https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcNzK.jpg

I want to switch to D, and the only thing i can see fro any of the Microsoft help docs and posts is "You can change this upon fresh installation". 
Which this is. I've uninstalled anything else remotely like it just to be sure.

Do any of you have any ideas or any experience with this issue, or anything i can try? I simply don't have enough space to install on C, and because of this, i can't start learning c# which is required for work.

Thanks so much in advance guys, it's really getting me worried now.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can only guess why Visual Studio is locking down the SDK path, here's a few workarounds and recommendations:

1. In your screenshot, the installer warns you about possible performance effects of installing Visual Studio on your D drive. I assume this is because your D drive is not an SSD. Microsoft's [Visual Studio system requirements document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs) recommends that you **install to an SSD**, and based on community experience, this is one recommendation you really want to stick to, otherwise IDE responsiveness may be well below your expectations, especially if you decide to install extensions in future.
2. Instead, you might want to reconsider the set of components that you're installing. If you're only getting started with C#, you'll probably be just fine with developing class libraries, console and web applications targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core. If this is the case, you might want to go to the *Workloads* tab in the installer and **opt out of some of the heaviest workloads** (such as *Mobile development with .NET*). Consider only installing *.NET desktop development*, *ASP.NET and web development*, *Azure development* and *.NET Core cross-platform development*. If you only select these, your installation is going to be much slimmer.
3. If minimizing Visual Studio installation as shown above isn't enough, consider an alternative way of setting up your .NET development environment. For example, you can [download](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) and install *.NET Core SDK and .NET Core Runtime*, and use one of the two most prominent **alternative code editors**: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [JetBrains Rider](https://jetbrains.com/rider) that are both quite compact.

Comment: With option 3, do i only need the Core stuff on the left? and not the Framework options on the right? Im sure i have those? option 3 is a great idea! Thank you so much for your help. I looked at only installing minimum specs, but about 4 or 5 of the options in the list you get to choose from, instantly bring it up above 20gb! it's crazy. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @TonyAnthonyQuigley Yes, you can just install .NET Core (items on the left) unless you specifically want to develop a Windows desktop application (in which case you'll need the full .NET Framework). .NET Core should be enough for console apps, libraries and web apps.

Comment: Listen thank you so much, i was half expecting someone with authority to come on and tell me "How DARE you write a message on our boards here with a spelling mistake in it! You're banned". haha. Thanks brother, I've got it sorted, much appreciated. T

Comment: @TonyAnthonyQuigley You're welcome. Now that your problem is sorted, can you fix the spelling that you know isn't quite right, and also embed one of the two pictures that currently link to imgur? This will help other visitors glancing through existing questions. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again Jura, Thank you so much for your assistance the other day. The solution we decided on from you though technically does work, but unfortunately it's very clunky, messy and slow when doing things like compiling (trying to just compile hello world goes through a whole array of processing and leaving all info of whats its doing in the output window and then finally i see "Hello World" Mixed up withinn it.

Comment: So basically, unless you have a Solid State C drive that has roughly 47gb (Minimum) of free space, you can't use, and therefor i can't learn C#. Whats so important about this C Drive? And as far as i have seen, C# is the only language that appears to need a minimum of 45gb on your C drive (and has to be SSD) to use it. I'm worried that I'm actually going to have to quit it, and pick another language. I can't get a bigger SSD for a C drive. Whats your opinion brother? Ty